# How to search a linked list for a structure object

Tags: c++, linked-list, structure, nodes

for this program I am not allowed to use vectors or std::.

I have a program called `StudentList.cpp` that uses a linked list class and a structure that stores the students' info from a file. The `removeStudent` function asks the user to enter a student ID number. I build a temporary Student object and search the linked list for the id number. If the student is found then I display the student's entire record and remove the student.

**This is where I am having problems. In the `removeStudent` function, I can't call the remove functions correcly.**  When I call the `remove` function from `LinkedList.h` I get the following error message:

`error message: a reference type "Student &" (non const-quaified) cannot be initialized with value type "int"`

Here are the functions I am having trouble with from the `StudentList.cpp` program:

```
void removeStudent(LinkedList<Student> &list)
{
    int id; 

    cout << "Please enter student ID number: ";
    cin >> id;

    Student temp;    //structure Student temporary object

    if (list.remove(temp.id) == false)      //error message: a reference type "Student &" (non const-quaified) cannot be initialized with value type "int"
        cout << "Student not found.\n";
    else
    {
        cout << id << endl;
        cout << "Student removed.\n";
    }
}
```

I have a program called `LinkedList.h` that includes functions working with a linked list. I know this program works just fine. The function I am calling from `removeStudent` is:

```
template <class TYPE>
bool LinkedList<TYPE>::remove(TYPE &dataOut)
{
    bool success = false;
    Node<TYPE> *pTemp = front;
    Node<TYPE> *pPrev = nullptr;

    while (pTemp != nullptr && pTemp->data < dataOut)
    {
        pPrev = pTemp;
        pTemp = pTemp->next;
    }
    if (pTemp != nullptr && pTemp->data == dataOut)
    {
        dataOut = pTemp->data;
        if (pPrev != nullptr)
            pPrev->next = pTemp->next;
        else
            front = pTemp->next;

        delete pTemp;
        success = true;
    }

    return success;

}
```

Comment: I'll admit, I just skimmed, but that's a lot of text and code. What's the question? Do you need help iterating over a structure, or checking for a match?

Comment: [mcve] minimal is key

Comment: @KennyOstrom In both the removeStudent and findStudent functions, I can't call the retrieve functions correcly.

Comment: If you aren't allowed to use std::vector then just use std::list - it is a linked list but it has a standard interface.

Comment: This is just wrong: `name = strcpy(right.name, name);`  For one thing you have the arguments are the wrong way around.  Also, you don't need to assign the result to anything because strcpy already did that

Comment: Also, major is an array - you can't assign one array to another.  That's why strcpy is used for character arrays that have nul terminators.  If major has a null terminator use strcpy.  If not use memcpy.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah we don't use std:: for anything

Comment: So you are stuck on how to write the `.remove()` member function? I don't see an implementation. If that is where you are stuck you can use the [.delnode()](https://pastebin.com/Sq1MPU15) function from the example. (deleting a node from a singly linked list is always the same). You iterate using both the *address-of* the node pointer and the pointer itself which avoids any special cases. See [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/)

Comment: I removed everything that was not relevant to make this more clear

Comment: OH, you have a compiler error message? POST THAT. We need the one line where you try to call list.remove, we need the prototype for list::remove (which you can find in LinkedList.h) and we need the full, exact error message. That should make for a short question. The error message is already telling you what's wrong, but we can expand on that.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I updated my question for you. I am so sorry I made this so confusing for yall. I guess I didn't really understand what I was trying to ask. I hope I made this more clear. Any help would is appreciated.

Comment: This is much better, Meagan. Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the update. You are calling a function which expects one data type, but passing it a different datatype. The compiler correctly rejects this because you gave it the wrong data type.

```
template<class TYPE>
class LinkedList {
public:
    bool remove(TYPE& x);
};

template <class TYPE>
bool LinkedList<TYPE>::remove(TYPE& dataOut)
{
    return false;
}

struct Student { int id; };

int main() {
    LinkedList<Student> list;

    int id = 1;
    list.remove(id); // reproduced error here

    Student temp{ id };
    list.remove(temp); // correct here
}
```

That code gives this error:

> error C2664: 'bool LinkedList::remove(TYPE &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'TYPE &'

The code compiles and runs if I comment out the bad line. Note that the next lines call list.remove with an instance of Student.

The exact text of the error will differ by compiler, but essentially you passed it an integer, but it expected a reference to a Student object.

(also you didn't initialize that variable, but that's a completely different issue)

Since the class it a template class, when you look at the prototype "bool LinkedList::remove(TYPE& dataOut)" you know that it has to be of some type that is not specified in the template class. It is actually decided here:

```
LinkedList<Student> list;  
           ^^^^^^^
```

TYPE is Student, but it doesn't matter that it was a template. That just made it a tiny bit harder to read the header and know what type the function expects.